# Diagnosing lamp electrical issues: 3-socket floor lamp has resistance for each socket, but no power

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, lamp, multimeter

I am trying to fix [this floor lamp](https://www.google.com/aclk?sa=l&ai=DChcSEwiK3Z7vma76AhUnF9QBHRP2CMQYABABGgJvYQ&sig=AOD64_0OX8rmw829h2Ma64MotCzSQQr_Qw&adurl&ctype=46&ved=2ahUKEwilqpPvma76AhW3kWoFHfPyB7oQzzl6BAgBEDU)

It is a standing floor lamp with 3 bulbs and a rotating switch that has 3 positions: 1 bulb on, 2 bulbs on, 3 bulbs on, or off

A couple of weeks ago I saw a spark near one of the highest bulb when I turned the switch.

- I checked the resistance of the wider prong of the cord and the edges of the sockets. The 2 lower sockets showed resistance. The top socket where I saw the spark showed no resistance
- I replaced the socket and there was still no resistance. I guess I should have check the wire connected to the socket for resistance because this didn’t solve the problem
- I took the top sconce apart and turns out the wire had shorted and melted behind the socket. I cut the wire behind the short, attached fresh wire, used shrink tube because there was no room at all for wire nuts, put the sconce back together, and wired the new socket back on
- Resistance between the larger prong of the cord and the edge of the socket was restored for the top socket, so all 3 sockets show resistance
- However, when I plug the lamp in and turn the switch, nothing happens. No light

I am stumped what to do or diagnose next. I am thinking maybe the switch is the issue, but that would be a lot of work to get out. Is there a way I could diagnose what’s happening now? Could you help?

Comment: You're measuring resistances down the *neutral*.  Neutral doesn't go through the switch.

Comment: As an update, there was a fuse inside of the switch which had blown. I swapped out the switch and it worked

Answer (score 0):

> Resistance between the larger prong of the cord and the edge of the socket was restored for the top socket, so all 3 sockets show resistance.

That is great for the neutral.

However the switch is switching the Hot.

Check that.

Comment: Oh I see. So with my multi-meter set to resistance, if I don't get a reading between the smaller prong of the cord and the inner base of the socket where the hot is, I can assume the switch is bad?

Comment: correct .........